# not able to generate bitmap with the python imaging library

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to generate a bitmap image, based on coordinates, resolution and greyscale. Basically the image should be coloured only inside those points area. I have tried this, but I keep getting errors like 'cannot determine region size; use 4-item box'. Here is what I tried:

```html
from PIL import Image

img = Image.new('L', (1200, 800), 120)
img.paste([2, 3, -4, 4])
img.show()
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. You want to colour a greyscale image? And you want to paste an image on top of another image, yet you only have a single image?

Comment: @MarkSetchell let's presume a transparent background of resolution 1200x800 and I wanna draw onit, the object defined by 2 pairs of coordinates with a grayscale colour. that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# Create empty canvas
im = Image.new('L', (1200, 800), 0)

# Create a draw context and draw rectangle at given position
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.rectangle(((100, 100), (1100,700)), fill='gray')

# Save result
im.save('result.png')
```

[image]

---

If you want a transparent canvas, and to draw a solid shape, you can use:

```
im = Image.new('LA', (1200, 800), 0)
```

which will give you a 2-channel image with Lightness (greyscale) and Alpha (transparency).

Then draw solid mid-grey rectangle with:

```
draw.rectangle(((100, 100), (1100,700)), fill=(128,255))
```

because 128 is in the middle of [0-255] and 255 will mean "opaque".

Comment: Thank you. Yet, isn't it possible to use draw.bitmap for 2 sets coordinates ? apparently it takes only 1 set or how do `I convert this to a bitmap then ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I asked in the comments why you only had one image if you want to paste a second image on top of a background and you said you wanted to draw an object - so I drew the obvious object - a rectangle. Do you want to draw an object or paste another image? Maybe add an image to your question showing what sort of result you are expecting...